# Filter groups based on occurrence of a value

Tags: python, pandas

Given the following DataFrame how can I filter groups based if a value is in the group?

For example in this table I would like to retain the groups which contain "FB" in the department

```
Job Dept
123 TC
123 TC
123 TC
123 FB
123 FB
123 MD
456 FB
456 FB
456 FB
456 FB
```

I would like the output to a table or dataframe like this.

```
Job Dept
123 TC
123 TC
123 TC
123 FB
123 FB
123 MD
```

I know I can check if "TC" in in the column by using

`df['Dept'].isin(["TC"].any()`

I don't know how to use apply, or whatever else, to figure this out by group and return a dataframe of only those groups.

Comment: Sorry I'm confused by what you want and the output, you state you want to filter the results where 'FB' is in the 'Dept' but you then only have 'Job' rows and rows where the 'Dept' values is clearly not 'FB', can you explain?

Comment: I wanted to be able to filter groups by the occurrence of a value within that group. So in this case if I group by "Job" I want to filter by groups that contain "TC" in "Dept". I do NOT want just the rows that contain "TC". I made a mistake on my original question in regards to "FB"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured out the answer. I was looking at apply but I needed to use filter

```
df.groupby("Job").filter(lambda x : x["Dept"].isin(["TC"]).any())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can index:

```
df[df['dept'] == 'FB']
```

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing