# SQL filter group based on occurrence of attribute

Tags: sql, filtering

Is it possible in (T-)SQL to filter groups of records by the occurrence of a specific value, like [this question about a Python dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28115894/filter-groups-based-on-occurrence-of-a-value)?

For instance, out of the following table I want the full groups as output that contain 16 as `Value`.

```
ID Group Value
1    1   10
2    1   12
3    1   16
4    2   10
5    2   14
6    2   18
7    3   12
8    3   16
9    3   18
```

The resulting output I want is

```
ID Group Value
1    1   10
2    1   12
3    1   16
7    3   12
8    3   16
9    3   18
```

According to the documentation and to the errors I get, `GROUP BY` or `PARTITION BY` and `HAVING` works only when summing the total value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM tableName
WHERE group in 
(SELECT distinct group from tableName where value = 16)
```

Inner query will list down all the groups with `value = 16`. Outer query will select rows with only those group.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT *
FROM tab t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM tab t2
              WHERE t1.[group] = t2.[group]
                AND t2.[Value] = 16)
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer! It works well! I tried it with `(SELECT * FROM tab t2` instead of `(SELECT 1 FROM tab t2`